# C syntax of a stream not associated to any peripheral

Tags: c, file-io, stdio

I quote below the second edition of The C Programming Language.

B.1 Input and output : <stdio.h>, § 2:

> A *stream* is a source or destinaton of data that may be associated with a disk or other peripheral.

Then one could say that a stream *may not* be associated to any peripheral : that a stream *can exist* without being associated to any peripheral.

Therefore the following question come : what look like a stream that is not associated to any peripheral ?

Considering that the authors

B.1 Input and output : <stdio.h>, § 3:

> [...] use "file pointer" and "stream" interchangeably [...]

Is

```
FILE *p;
p = NULL;
```

such a good answer ?

Comment: `fopencookie` can be associated with... whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "file pointer" and "stream" are indeed used as strict synonyms, then:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
```

defines a *stream* that is not (yet) associated with any peripheral. Nor is it
(yet) associated with any source or destination of data.

If you were to ask Brian Kernighan or the late Denis Ritchie, "Is `fp` really a steam there?",
they'd probably say "Well, maybe not. It's a stream whenever it's *in use* for I/O - when you successfully open it, until you
successfully close it. It's no big deal whether you say it's a stream when it's not in use, or just a file pointer."

A file pointer (or stream) that's in use for I/O is the programmatic representation in C of some
source or destination of data. That source or destination might be - or be on - a peripheral device
such as a USB stick, SSD or HDD, tape volume or terminal. Or it might not. *The definition of C
does not specify or restrict the physical implementation of the sources or destinations of data that a* `FILE *` *can represent*. That's why the book says that a source or destination of data *may* be associated with a disk or other peripheral.

The C Standard Library provides only the function [`fopen`, in `<stdio,h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) (and it's fortified variant `fopen_s`) as
a way of creating a stream from scratch.<sup>1</sup> And it provides the well-known ready-made `FILE *` streams `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.
The streams thus provided by `<stdio.h>` are normally, but not necessarily, associated with peripheral devices.

C libraries other than the Standard Library may provide you with functions
returning a `FILE *` stream that is not associated with a peripheral device. E.g. the
Linux C Library offers you [`fmemopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream) and friends,
which provide `FILE *` I/O to *memory regions*.

You can even read or write `FILE *` streams in memory using only the `<stdio.h>` facilities. Linux
allows you easily to create a [`tmpfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/tmpfs.5.html) virtual in-memory
filesystem. You may then write programs purely in Standard C that perform regular `FILE *` I/O
in your `tmpfs` filesystem, and none of it will be associated with a peripheral device.
C does not know or care about the implementation of the filesystem.

---

[1] There's also `freopen` and `freopen_s`, which close an existing stream and open
it again with a new filename.

Comment: Enlightening. I didn't have such reading of the _may_ operator for the quote I mentionned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define 'peripheral'.  There are special devices that are not "peripherals" in the sense of a piece of hardware attached to a machine.

For example, `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero` are two such devices. If you open those (`/dev/zero` for reading, `/dev/null` for reading or writing), then associate a stream with it, they're not really communicating with a peripheral.  You could argue the same for `/dev/random` and/or `/dev/urandom`, too (they're read-only).

On Linux, you can open files under the `/proc` file system — they're not directly associated with a peripheral.

Comment: Maybe we could see the concept of "peripheral" as a subset of "file" or "device" (assuming "file" and "device" are synonymous). Then we could distinguish, in the first place, two types of "devices" : "peripherals" and "non-peripherals". Thus we could write the generic form of stream non-associated to any "file" or "device" : `FILE *p = NULL;`, but not such for a stream non-associated to any "peripheral" (in this case, as you mentionned, only `FILE *p = fopen("/dev/null", "r");` or  `FILE *p = fopen("/dev/zero", "r");`, etc. woud be suitable.)

Comment: I didn't mention pseudo-terminals or pseudo-ttys (same thing). They're tricky. On the whole, they're not peripherals. These days, green screen terminals are a relic of the distant past for most people, but a terminal is a window in a GUI interface. That might more or less count as a peripheral. I'm not sure there's a useful distinction here. A file stream is a file stream is a file stream. There are streams on which you can seek (disk files including SSD, maybe tape drives) and many more on which you can't (pipes, FIFOs, sockets, ...). If this is a homework question, study the course notes.

Comment: This is not a homework question. Since I'm quite new into C programming, I read the K&R book when I need to understand something in a conceptual way. I know that the concept of stream is an high-level one so it can apply to many different devices. Thus maybe, a syntectical and systematic understanding of it is quite complicate without being on a deeper level. As you can see in my text, I'm tryna figure things out with some very basic code.

Comment: I would regard `FILE *fp = NULL;` as a 'non-stream' or 'failed to open' stream.  It isn't a stream; it certainly isn't connected to any peripheral.  To a large extent, Unix (and, even more so, Plan9) treats everything as a file.  This is a terrific unifying concept.  It means you don't have to worry most of the time about what the file stream is reading from or writing to.  If it's a readable stream, you can read from it.  If it's a writable stream, you can write to it.  And most of the time, that's sufficient.  In effect, you don't have to worry about whether it's connected to a peripheral.

Comment: Reading the K&R book, I was thinking : since one write `FILE *fp;` it exist a stream (`fp`), no matter one can do with it. (As it exist an integer pointer since one write `int *p;`, whatever can be done with `p`.)

Comment: It is said here `https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Concepts.html#I_002fO-Concepts` that _the connection to an open file is represented either as a stream or as file descriptor_. Thus, with the following snippet of code : `FILE *fp;` one can't say that `fp` is a stream. A variable pointing to a `FILE` struct is not yet a stream. `fp` needs to point to a `FILE` structure that actually stand for a file or device. Then we could say that the concept of `stream` remains in the design and the _use_ of such structures.